# Pass parameter to component

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I have the following Angular 6 component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-site-layout',
  templateUrl: './site-layout.component.html'
})

export class SiteLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() version: string;

}
```

And I have the following route definition:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

  { 
    path: '', 
    component: SiteLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
      { path: 'team', component: TeamComponent }
    ]
  }

  // Other routes

]
```

Is it possible to pass a version value in:

```
{ path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
```

I am using `SiteLayoutComponent` as a "master page" for other pages.

`SiteLayoutComponent` has small differences according to a version value.

For example, `AboutComponent` might need to use version 1 of `SiteLayoutComponent` and `TeamComponent` might use version 2 of `SiteLayoutComponent` and `TeamComponent`.

Does this make sense?

**Update**

I created and online example:

http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxxfff

When "Team" is clicked it should appear "Layout Component 1.0" but appears "Layout Component".

What am I missing?

Comment: I have posted an answer , I am not sure this is you are exactly looking for

Comment: I can't see your answer. Did you deleted it?

Comment: Could you please refresh , I have deleted and reposted again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52430467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the version as data on your child route like this

```
{ 
    path: '', 
    component: SiteLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent,data: { version: "1.0" } },
      { path: 'team', component: TeamComponent,data: { version: "2.0" } }
    ]
  }
```

You can access the same by using **ActivateRoute** from your parent component(**SiteLayoutComponent**) and do the changes based on the version

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,

  ) {}


var version= this.route.snapshot.firstChild.data["version"]
```

Useful link

[How can I access an activated child route's data from the parent route's component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806188/how-can-i-access-an-activated-child-routes-data-from-the-parent-routes-compone)

Comment: I created an online example with your suggestion: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxxfff ... When you click on "Team" it should appear "Layout Component 1.0" but appears only "Layout Component". What am I missing?

Comment: @MiguelMoura it's because you are returning the version in to a variable , so angular assume it as a private and could't access in to the html. Instead create a property. see the update stack blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a3kfnb?file=src/app/layout.component.ts

Comment: @MiguelMoura Did you checked the updated stackblitz??

Comment: Yes, I checked it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

follow this

```
{ path: 'about/:version', component: AboutComponent }

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class SiteLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

version: string;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty('pid') && params['pid'] != ''{
     this.version = params['version']; 
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: I don't want the parameter to be in the about route. I mean, what I need is to set which version of the SiteComponentLayout is used by the AboutComponentLayout. And it will be always the same.

Comment: I added an update with an online example. It is almost working. Only the parameter value is not being displayed. What am I missing?