# Angular 6: Search specific word in the current route

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, parent-child

I have this routing table:

```js
// Routing array - set routes to each html page
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/courses', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'courses', component: CourseListComponent,  pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'courses/:id', component: CourseDetailComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'courses/:id/unit/:unitId', component: CoursePlayComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: CourseListComponent },
      { path: 'lesson/:lessonId', component: CourseLessonComponent, data: 'lesson },
      { path: 'quiz/:quizId', component: CourseQuizComponent, data: 'quiz, }
  ]},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }];
```

```js
//Course-Play.component
     
     constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
          private route: ActivatedRoute,
          private router: Router,
          public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
            route.url.subscribe(() => {
                console.log(route.snapshot.children.data); }); // <-- undefined
          }
          
     ngOnInit() {
     
     // this is what I want to do but I don't know how
     if (this.route.snapshot.children.data == 'lesson) {
        // activate lesson children
      }
      else {
        // activate quiz children
       }
     
     }
```

In ngOnInit in course-play I want to know if the route is lesson/:lessonId or quiz/:quizId. I only need to know if there's lesson or quiz in the route and then activate different child.
I know how to do it with params (with route.snapshot) but not with a static text.

EDIT: tried to use data but it's not working

Comment: Instead of searching for a specific text, have you considered using the route's `data` attribute? It's still using route.snapshot, though it's a better approach than searching for a string, especially when variables are part of a route. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806188/how-can-i-access-an-activated-child-routes-data-from-the-parent-routes-compone

Comment: I'll see, but I use mat-sidebar and the body is change depends on the children. Lessons are working but the quiz not. when I enter this route "courses/3/unit/1/quiz/1 it's loading a lesson and not a quiz. When I click on the quiz in the side-bar the quiz appear below the lesson instead only the quiz in the body

Comment: I tried to do this but it's said it's undefined (I added to the table root data also) :        route.url.subscribe(() => {
            console.log(route.snapshot.children.data); });

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible approach (within your component's `ngOnInit`), `this.route` being injected to your constructor as an `ActivatedRoute`:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.url.subscribe((urlSegments: UrlSegment[]) => {
    switch (urlSegments[4].path) {
      case 'lesson':
        // ...
        break;
      case 'quiz':
        // ...
    }
  });
}
```

Edit: just realized you're using children components, I'm not sure how the segments behave in that case. Give it a try, I'll delete this answer if this can't work.

Comment: what is Fragments and UrlSegments?

Comment: Sorry, by fragments I also meant segments. Segments are parts/of/the/route/URL.

Comment: I'll try use what you wrote and tell you if it's working. I tried use data in routing table and access children.data but it was undefined. I edited the source code also

Comment: Sure, feel free to `console.log(urlSegments)` to see what it looks like. You might need to make some small adjustments.

Comment: it didn't work, it's said that: TpeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined. what the index represent? and what the subscribe? maybe the index isn't right?

Comment: Yeah the index might be wrong as I'm a bit unfamiliar with children routes; try using `console.log` to see what `urlSegments` contains. Or `urlSegments.forEach(urlSegment => console.log(urlSegment.path));`.

Comment: it seems that urlSegments[1].path = 3 but from there the others are undefined and urlSegments.path = undefined

Comment: ok so urlSegments[1] = 3, urlSegments[2] = unit, urlSegments[3] = 2 but 4 and 5 are giving me error

Comment: OK then it seems like the subroute's segments are not available here, so this won't work. Sorry about that!

Comment: that's ok you tried to help :) do you know how to work with the data field in routing table? I tried using that but it's undefined :( in the angular site they don't use examples with that

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806188/how-can-i-access-an-activated-child-routes-data-from-the-parent-routes-compone) may help.

Comment: I read this but I didn't understand the solution. why I can't just use children.data? why all this code? I'm using Angular 6 so maybe there's code that irrelevant to me. I'll edit the code because I added some stuff