# Angular - pass data to host component upon routing to lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a module with the following routing:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: PagesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        data: { test: 'snoop' },
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './modules/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
      },
      {
        data: { test: 'dogg' },
        path: 'admin', 
        loadChildren: './modules/admin/admin.module#AdminModule' 
      }
    ]
  }
```

What I'd like to do is pass some data to the `PagesComponent` component, depending on which lazy loaded module you've loaded.

So, in my `PagesComponent` I'd like to have something like this:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

And the `data` param will then contain the data defined in the root.

I know I can easily retrieve the data from the routes within the lazy loaded module component itself, but is it possible to get this data in the host component, i.e. `PagesComponent`?

Background: I'd like to do this so I can display different data in the menu depending on which page you're currently on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access an activated child route's data from the parent route's component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806188/how-can-i-access-an-activated-child-routes-data-from-the-parent-routes-compone)

Comment: @Lends but I'm using lazy loaded modules here.

Comment: my fault, but the answer is almost the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between lazy-loaded and [simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806188/how-can-i-access-an-activated-child-routes-data-from-the-parent-routes-compone)  routes' data is that you have to look deeper.

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
  route.url.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(route.snapshot.firstChild.firstChild.data);
   });
}
```